# Loop works outside function but in functions it doesn't.

Tags: r, function, loops

Been going around for hours with this. My 1st question online on R. Trying to creat a function that contains a loop. The function takes a vector that the user submits like in pollutantmean(4:6) and then it loads a bunch of csv files (in the directory mentioned) and binds them. What is strange (to me) is that if I assign the variable id and then run the loop without using a function, it works! When I put it inside a function so that the user can supply the id vector then it does nothing. Can someone help ? thank you!!!

```
pollutantmean<-function(id=1:332) 
       {
      #read files
      allfiles<-data.frame()
      id<-str_pad(id,3,pad = "0")
      direct<-"/Users/ped/Documents/LearningR/"
              for (i in id) {
               path<-paste(direct,"/",i,".csv",sep="")
               file<-read.csv(path)
               allfiles<-rbind(allfiles,file)
                             }
       }
```

Comment: Your function is missing a return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is missing a return value. (@Roland)

```
pollutantmean<-function(id=1:332) {
  #read files
  allfiles<-data.frame()
  id<-str_pad(id,3,pad = "0")
  direct<-"/Users/ped/Documents/LearningR/"
          for (i in id) {
           path<-paste(direct,"/",i,".csv",sep="")
           file<-read.csv(path)
           allfiles<-rbind(allfiles,file)
                         }
 return(allfiles)
   }
```

Edit:
Your mistake was that you did not specify in your function what you want to get out from the function. In R, you create objects inside of function (you could imagine it as different environment) and then specify which object you want it to return.

With my comment about accepting my answer, I meant [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): (...To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in...).

Comment: thanks a lot for the quick reply! thats interesting because R prints the  start of the file (don't think it prints the whole file, looks short , maybe 1st iteration only of loop) but doesn't "build" the allfiles file.

Comment: @Pepe So my answer helped? I did not get it from your comment. If so consider accepting it..

Comment: It  definitely helped ! but I am also very interested in finding out what I am doing wrong so that I can learn. thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: if you're trying to join multiple file reads, then you probably want the value of i to change, right?
    for (i in id)

should probably be 
   for(i in 1:id){

Comment: @WHoekstra , yes but the argument of the function supplies that range. pollutantmean(2:4). id is a range. thank you!

Comment: @Pepe Hi, I tried to explain your mistake and edited my answer, also I added comment about accepting answers.

Answer (score 0):

Consider even an `lapply` and `do.call` which would not need `return` being last line of function:

```
pollutantmean <- function(id=1:332) {    
  id <- str_pad(id,3,pad = "0")
  direct_files <- paste0("/Users/ped/Documents/LearningR/", id, ".csv")

  # READ FILES INTO LIST AND ROW BIND
  allfiles <- do.call(rbind, lapply(direct_files, read.csv))
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot! I'll try that. Was wondering though why what I did doesn't work.  I think that its the way the argument "id" is being passed to function. But can figure out what exactly is the issue.

Answer (score 0):

ok, I got it. I was expecting the files that are built to be actually created and show up in the environment of R. But for some reason they don't.  But R still does all the calculations. Thanks  lot for the replies!!!!

```
pollutantmean<-function(directory,pollutant,id) 
{
  #read files
  allfiles<-data.frame()
  id2<-str_pad(id,3,pad = "0")
  direct<-paste("/Users/pedroalbuquerque/Documents/Learning R/",directory,sep="") 
  for (i in id2) {
    path<-paste(direct,"/",i,".csv",sep="")
    file<-read.csv(path)
    allfiles<-rbind(allfiles,file)
  }
#averaging polutants 
mean(allfiles[,pollutant],na.rm = TRUE)
}

pollutantmean("specdata","nitrate",23:35)
```

Comment: Sorry, but did you notice changes I made to my answer(http://stackoverflow.com/a/43209515/7063375)?